# how to filter data based on unique categories in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset given below:

```
time          company       category       country_cd       price 
01/01/2020       1             A               1              10
02/01/2020       1             A               1              20
03/01/2020       1             B               1              30
04/01/2020       1             B               1              40
01/01/2020       2             A               2              50
02/01/2020       2             A               2              60
03/01/2020       2             A               1              70
04/01/2020       2             A               1              80
01/01/2020       3             A               1              90
02/01/2020       3             A               1              100
03/01/2020       3             A               1              110
04/01/2020       3             B               1              120
01/01/2020       4             A               1              130
02/01/2020       4             B               2              140
```

I am trying to get the unique {`company, country_cd`} pairs which have more than 1 unique `category`. After filtering, the expected data (python pandas dataframe) is given below:

```
time          company       category       country_cd       price 
01/01/2020       1             A               1              10
02/01/2020       1             A               1              20
03/01/2020       1             B               1              30
04/01/2020       1             B               1              40
01/01/2020       3             A               1              90
02/01/2020       3             A               1              100
03/01/2020       3             A               1              110
04/01/2020       3             B               1              120
```

Is there any efficient way to do with python? This is a small snipped for illustration, real data is much more bigger than it. So, iterating based on unique {`company, country_cd`} and checking its `unique(category)>1` column is not a good option for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform`, combined with `nunique` to filter for rows that have more than 1 unique category :

```
df.loc[df.groupby(["company", "country_cd"]).category.transform("nunique").gt(1)]

          time  company category  country_cd  price
0   01/01/2020        1        A           1     10
1   02/01/2020        1        A           1     20
2   03/01/2020        1        B           1     30
3   04/01/2020        1        B           1     40
8   01/01/2020        3        A           1     90
9   02/01/2020        3        A           1    100
10  03/01/2020        3        A           1    110
11  04/01/2020        3        B           1    120
```

The `transform` function returns a Series, that is the same length as the original dataframe. When combined with the `greater than` method, a boolean Series is returned, which is then used to filter the original dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can group your DataFrame by `company` and `country_cd` and calculate the number of unique categories per group. Then, filter the result for only groups with more than on category and filter the original DataFrame based on the resulting groups:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """time          company       category       country_cd       price 
01/01/2020       1             A               1              10
02/01/2020       1             A               1              20
03/01/2020       1             B               1              30
04/01/2020       1             B               1              40
01/01/2020       2             A               2              50
02/01/2020       2             A               2              60
03/01/2020       2             A               1              70
04/01/2020       2             A               1              80
01/01/2020       3             A               1              90
02/01/2020       3             A               1              100
03/01/2020       3             A               1              110
04/01/2020       3             B               1              120
01/01/2020       4             A               1              130
02/01/2020       4             B               2              140"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep="\s+")

grouped = df.groupby(["company", "country_cd"], as_index=False).category.nunique()
grouped = grouped[grouped.category > 1]
df.merge(grouped, how="inner", on=["company", "country_cd"], suffixes=["", "_grouped"]).drop("category_grouped", axis=1)
```

Which results in:

```
         time  company category  country_cd  price
0  01/01/2020        1        A           1     10
1  02/01/2020        1        A           1     20
2  03/01/2020        1        B           1     30
3  04/01/2020        1        B           1     40
4  01/01/2020        3        A           1     90
5  02/01/2020        3        A           1    100
6  03/01/2020        3        A           1    110
7  04/01/2020        3        B           1    120
```